# Why does my Typescript import only work if I do "console.log(myImport)"?

Tags: angularjs, import, typescript, jspm

I'm trying to load my Angular `1.5.2` app (written with Typescript) with JSPM `0.17.0`.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="jspm.browser.js"></script>
    <script src="jspm.config.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main first-name="huh" last-name="what"></main>
    <script>
      SystemJS.import('app.ts');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For my `./app.ts`, **this DOESN'T work ↓**

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import angular from 'angular'
import main from './components/main/main.ts';

module app {

    angular.module('MyApp', [
        'main'
    ])

}

// which gives me "[$injector:nomod] Module 'main' is not available!"
```

**this DOES work ↓**

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import angular from 'angular'
import main from './components/main/main.ts';

module app {

     angular.module('MyApp', [
        'main'
    ])

    console.log(main);

}

// Now it works fine, no error.
```

So why does this fail unless I refer to my imported module explicitly with `console.log(main)` in the module declaration? What is broken with my import syntax?

Comment: I think `;` semicolon after `angular.module('MyApp', [
        'main'
    ])` is missing

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid triggering side-effects, [imports are not loaded until referenced in a module](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit).

credit to Ryan Cavanaugh